# 1)$A\subset X$ subset, then $\text{Int}(A)=\emptyset \iff \overline{A^{c}}=X$? 2)...

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

$X$ is a metric space. Is it true that if $A\subset X$ subset, then $\text{Int}(A)=\emptyset \iff A^{c}$ is dense in $X$? And that $G$ is dense in $X$ $\iff$ $\forall\omega$ open nonempty in $X$ $\omega \cap G \neq \emptyset$?

For the *first question* I've tried to answer in this way (here I will denote $(T)'$ the set of all the limit points of $T$):

$(\implies)$ By contradiction: $x\in \text{Int}(A)$ $\implies$ $\exists r>0$ s.t. $B(x,r)\subset A$ $\implies B(x,r) \cap A^{c}=\emptyset \implies x \not\in (A^{c})^{'} \implies x\not \in A^{c}\cup(A^{c})^{'}=\overline{A^{c}}$ and then $A^{c}$ is not dense.

$(\impliedby)$ By definition we know $\text{Int}(A)=\{x\in A|\exists r>0 \text{ s.t. } B(X,r)\subset A\}$. If $A=\emptyset$ it's trivial ($A^{c}=X$). Otherwise: $x\in A$ then, because $\text{Int}(A)=\emptyset$, $\forall r>0$ $B(x,r)\cap A^{c}\neq\emptyset \implies x\in (A^{c})^{'} \implies A\subset (A^{c})'$. Then: $\overline{A^c}=A^{c}\cup (A^{c})'= A^{c}\cup (A\cup (A^{c})' \setminus A)=X$.

For the *second question* I tried in this other way:

$(\implies)$ Let us suppose $\exists$ $\omega$ open nonempty s.t. $\omega \cap G = \emptyset$. We know $\forall x \in \omega$ $\exists r>0$ s.t. $B(x,r)\subset \omega$ then $B(x,r)\cap G=\emptyset \implies x\not \in G' \implies x \not\in \bar{G}=G\cup G' \implies G$ is not dense.

$(\impliedby)$  We assume that $\forall$ nonempty open $\omega$ we have $\omega \cap G \neq \emptyset$. If $G^{c}=\emptyset$ it is trivial. Otherwise, let $x_{0}\in G^{c}$, $\forall r>0$ $B(x_{0},r)$ is open $\implies$ $B(x_{0},r)\cap G \neq \emptyset \implies x_{0}\in G^{'} \implies G^{c}\subset G^{'}$. Then, $\bar{G}=G\cup G'=G\cup (G^{c}\cup (G'\setminus G^{c}))=X$.

Are they correct? Could anyone help me? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I think you might want to look at 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604126/empty-interior-equivalent-definitions-from-munkres

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Comment: I'd suggest shortening the proof along the following lines. For the first part: prove that $\operatorname{Int}(A)^c = \overline{A^c},$ for all $A \subset X.$ For the second part: take $A = G^c,$ getting $\big(\overline{G}\big)^c = \operatorname{Int}(G^c),$ for all $G \subset X.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the second: $G$ is dense in $X$ iff $G \cap O \neq \emptyset$ for all non-empty open subsets $O$ of $X$.

Left to right: Let $O \subseteq X$ be non-empty and open, so pick $x \in O$ and $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq O$, using $O$ is open. We know $x \in \overline{G} = G \cup G'$. If $x \in G$ we are done as trivially $O \cap G \neq \emptyset$ is then witnessed by $x$ itself. Otherwise $x \in G'$ and the definition of a limit point gives that $B(x,r)$ intersects $G$ in some point $y \neq x$. But then $y \in O \cap G$ as well, and $O \cap G$ is again non-empty.

Right to left: We want to show $G$ is dense, so let $x \in X$. If $x \in G$ we are again done, as $x \in \overline{G}$ right away. So assume $x \notin G$ and let $r>0$ be arbitrary, then $O=B(x,r)$ is a non-empty open set, so by assumption it intersects $G$ and this must be in another point than $x$, as we assumed $x \notin G$. So then $x \in G' \subseteq \overline{G}$ and we're done too.

For the first we want to see that $\operatorname{int}(A) \neq \emptyset \iff A^\complement \text{ is dense}$.

I'll apply the characterisation of dense sets I just showed:

Left to right: Suppose that $O$ is a non-empty open set of $X$. So pick $x \in O$. Then $O \subseteq A$ cannot hold, as then $x \in \operatorname{int}(A)$ which we assumed to be empty. So not all points of $O$ lie in $A$, so some point of $O$ lies in $A^\complement$, or $A^\complement \cap O \neq \emptyset$. As $O$ was arbitary non-empty open, $A^\complement$ is dense.

Right to left:

Suppose that there is some $x \in \operatorname{int}(A)$.
Then $O= \operatorname{int}(A)$ is non-empty open and because $\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq A$, we have that $O \cap A^\complement = \emptyset$. This contradicts the fact that $A^\complement$ is dense. Hence $\operatorname{int}(A) = \emptyset$.